# How do I handle image preview before upload in javascript? The code can't work twice on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, image

I am trying to build a web application that can allow a user to preview an image before upload, the code works well but if i copy and paste it on the same page the it only works for one part. eg I put the code same code into 2 separate div tags, one of the div tag is for web app while the second div tag is for mobile version of the application. Even when I tried to change the id still the javascript fails to load.

Below is my code

```
<div class="web_version">
           <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <textarea name="answer" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your answer here....."></textarea>
              </div>   <br>
                 <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="file" id="file"  onchange="loadImage(event)" style="display: none;">
                 <label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Photo<img src="my-img.png" alt="" width="40"></label>
                <img id="input" width="200" />

                <script>
                   var loadImage = function(event) {
                     var image = document.getElementById('input');
                     image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                  };
                </script>
                   <button type="submit" name="solution" class="btn btn-primary">Answer</button><br>
           </form>
        </div>

        <!-- Below is the code which is for the mobile version -->
        <div class="mobile_version">
           <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <textarea name="answer" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your answer here....."></textarea>
              </div>   <br>
                 <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="file" id="file"  onchange="loadImage(event)" style="display: none;">
                 <label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Photo<img src="my-img.png" alt="" width="40"></label>
                <img id="input" width="200" />

                <script>
                   var loadImage = function(event) {
                     var image = document.getElementById('input');
                     image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                  };
                </script>
                   <button type="submit" name="solution" class="btn btn-primary">Answer</button><br>
           </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Creating multiple elements with the same id is not valid markup. Define different ids for different containers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, putting `<script>` inside the `<form>` tag doesn't make it attached to the `<form>`. It's not how js works.

Both `<script> ... </script>` will be executed when page rendered. They will add the same function `loadImage` twice.

So, first thing you need to do is to split function `loadImage` to `loadImage1` and `loadImage2` for example.

Next thing is selector `document.getElementById('input')`. In both scripts that function will find the same FIRST input in the page (because it will search from start of page, not within `<form>` as you may think.

So you need to specify more clearly what input you want to use in particular form.
For example you can use `var image = document.querySelector('div.web_version input');`

Total solution:

```html
<div class="web_version">
           <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <textarea name="answer" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your answer here....."></textarea>
              </div>   <br>
                 <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="file" id="file"  onchange="loadImage1(event)" style="display: none;">
                 <label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Photo<img src="my-img.png" alt="" width="40"></label>
                <img id="input" width="200" />

                <script>
                   var loadImage1 = function(event) {
                     var image = document.querySelector('div.web_version input');
                     image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                  };
                </script>
                   <button type="submit" name="solution" class="btn btn-primary">Answer</button><br>
           </form>
        </div>

        <!-- Below is the code which is for the mobile version -->
        <div class="mobile_version">
           <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <textarea name="answer" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your answer here....."></textarea>
              </div>   <br>
                 <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="file" id="file"  onchange="loadImage2(event)" style="display: none;">
                 <label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Photo<img src="my-img.png" alt="" width="40"></label>
                <img id="input" width="200" />

                <script>
                   var loadImage2 = function(event) {
                     var image = document.querySelector('div.mobile_version input');
                     image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                  };
                </script>
                   <button type="submit" name="solution" class="btn btn-primary">Answer</button><br>
           </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Ohk thanks, I just copied the code you provided and pasted it but it doesn't work. Did u try to test it before please?